# How do I use my IFTTT backup code to get access to my account?

Tags: if-this-then-that, multi-factor-auth

When I enabled two-step verification, they told me that [the backup code is important](https://ifttt.com/help/account-security#enable-two-factor-authentication):

> Keep your backup code in a safe place! If you lose access to your
>   phone, this backup code will be necessary to access your IFTTT
>   account. For account security reasons, we will be unable to retrieve
>   your backup codes for you.

But IFTTT doesn't seem to have written anything on *how* to actually use the backup code to access your account.

Now, I have lost my old phone and can't use Google Authenticator to login to the IFTTT app on my new phone (iPhone 7) as the Authenticator data doesn't seem to have been saved in the iCloud backup I used to restore my phone.

I have my password as well as my backup code. This ought to be enough. But without proper instructions I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually very easy (as long as you try to log in on a desktop computer). You simple go to ifttt.com, log in using your username and password after which you are requested to enter your 6-digit code OR backup code. If you enter your backup code, 2-step verification is disabled. You can then enable it again as you did the first time.